# How to read text file's key, value pair using pandas and write to csv?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv, key-value

I want to parse a text file which contains following data.
The first four columns (Name, Date, Time and Activity) are always in the same order after that there is no fixed structure anymore

**Input.log**

```
Name: John Doe| Date: 30072022 | Time: 05:06| Activity: Call
Name: John Doe| Date: 30072022 | Time: 05:07| Activity: Search| Type: 99
Name: John Doe| Date: 30072022 | Time: 05:07| Activity: Search| Type: 99| Customer: 123456
Name: Hannah Parkes| Date: 10082022| Time: 13:16| Activity: Archiving| Customer: 0465755
Name: Shannon Harper| Date: 11082022| Time: 16:0 |Activity: Call
Name: Shannon Harper| Date: 11082022| Time: 17:15|Activity: Call Activity: Search| Type: 99| Customer: 985643
Name: Shannon Harper| Date: 11082022| Time: 17:16|Activity: Call Activity: Document| Customer: 985643| Customer type: FHR
Name:Rachel Bolton  | Date: 14092022| Time: 09:35|Activity: Search|Contract: 56575757| StartDate: 01-01-2021| EndDate: 29-07-2022
```

**Desired output (to CSV)**

```
+--------------+--------+-----+---------+----+--------+-------------+--------+----------+----------+
|Name          |Date    |Time |Activity |Type|Customer|Customer type|Contract|StartDate |EndDate   |
+--------------+--------+-----+---------+----+--------+-------------+--------+----------+----------+
|John Doe      |30072022|05:06|Call     |    |        |             |        |          |          |
|John Doe      |30072022|05:07|Search   |99  |        |             |        |          |          |
|John Doe      |30072022|05:07|Search   |99  |123456  |             |        |          |          |
|Hannah Parkes |10082022|13:16|Archiving|    |0465755 |             |        |          |          |
|Shannon Harper|11082022|16:05|Call     |    |        |             |        |          |          |
|Shannon Harper|11082022|17:15|Search   |99  |985643  |             |        |          |          |
|Shannon Harper|11082022|17:16|Document |    |985643  |FHR          |        |          |          |
|Rachel Bolton |14092022|09:35|Search   |    |        |             |56575757|01-01-2021|29-07-2022|
+--------------+--------+-----+---------+----+--------+-------------+--------+----------+----------+
```

**Already tried something like this;**

```
import pandas as pd

log_file = 'Input.log'
df = pd.read_csv(log_file, sep=";", index_col=None, names=['text'])
s = df.text.str.split('|', expand=True).stack().str.split(': ', expand=True)
print(s)
```

Any help to get this done is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I change data by expected ouput (remove `Activity: Call` ), then is possible change your solution with `MultiIndex` and reshape by [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
s = df.text.str.split('|', expand=True).stack().str.split(':', expand=True).apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())

ordering= s[0].unique()
df = s.droplevel(1).set_index(0, append=True)[1].unstack().reindex(ordering, axis=1)

print(df)
0            Name      Date   Time   Activity Type Customer Customer type  \
0        John Doe  30072022  05:06       Call  NaN      NaN           NaN   
1        John Doe  30072022  05:07     Search   99      NaN           NaN   
2        John Doe  30072022  05:07     Search   99   123456           NaN   
3   Hannah Parkes  10082022  13:16  Archiving  NaN  0465755           NaN   
4  Shannon Harper  11082022   16:0       Call  NaN      NaN           NaN   
5  Shannon Harper  11082022  17:15     Search   99   985643           NaN   
6  Shannon Harper  11082022  17:16   Document  NaN   985643           FHR   
7   Rachel Bolton  14092022  09:35     Search  NaN      NaN           NaN   

0  Contract   StartDate     EndDate  
0       NaN         NaN         NaN  
1       NaN         NaN         NaN  
2       NaN         NaN         NaN  
3       NaN         NaN         NaN  
4       NaN         NaN         NaN  
5       NaN         NaN         NaN  
6       NaN         NaN         NaN  
7  56575757  01-01-2021  29-07-2022
```